# How to filter timesheets xero uk with startDate and endDate?

Tags: php, xero-api

Im implementing xero uk in my projects and i want to filter timesheets with startDate and endDate

In documentation i see that i can filter with **Filter by employeeId and payrollCalendarId**

ex of the get api that i want to work : `https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/2.0/timesheets?filter=startDate>=2020-05-01 & endDate<2020-05-07`

Any help ?

Comment: Since this is API-specific, have you contacted them to find out how to use filters on their API?

Comment: Check their [documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/payroll-api-uk/timesheets), it has some information there.